# Duvida iteração dentro lista

Tags: python, lista, for

Como funciona o `for` dentro dessa lista?

```
list_liked = [i >= 4 for i in ratings]
```

Ele faz tipo um `if` e depois faz a iteração?

Comment: Sugiro você testar e ver o resultado por conta própria. Mas a resposta é não, ele na verdade faz um mapeamento e gera uma nova lista contendo False para os valores < 4 da lista original, e True para os valores >= 4.

Comment: Isso se chama [Compreensão de lista](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

Comment: valeu pela ajuda, comecei estudar python ontem haha

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Isso é uma [*list comprehension*](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

Basicamente, a estrutura é:

```py
lista = [ expressão for i in iterável ]
```

Que é equivalente a:

```py
lista = []
for i in iterável:
    lista.append(expressão)
```

Ou seja, para cada elemento do iterável, ele avalia o valor da expressão e coloca os resultados na lista final.

---

No seu caso, seria equivalente a:

```py
list_liked = []
for i in ratings:
    list_liked.append(i >= 4)
```

Ou seja, para cada elemento de `ratings` (que no *loop* foi chamado de `i`), ele pega o valor da expressão `i >= 4`, e adiciona este valor em `list_liked`.

Mas vale notar que a expressão `i >= 4` é uma comparação, e [segundo a documentação](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons), o resultado é um valor *booleano* (`True` ou `False`).

Portanto, o resultado será uma lista contendo apenas os valores *booleanos* `True` ou `False`. Exemplo:

```py
ratings = [1, 4, 3, 6]

list_liked = [i >= 4 for i in ratings]
# cria uma lista contendo True ou False
print(list_liked) # [False, True, False, True]
```

Como o primeiro e terceiro elementos de `ratings` são menores que 4, o resultado da comparação é `False`. Já o segundo e quarto elementos são maiores ou iguais a 4, e portanto o resultado da comparação é `True`. Por isso o resultado é a lista `[False, True, False, True]`.

Ou seja, neste caso ele não "*faz um `if`*". Ele simplesmente itera por todos os elementos, e para cada um ele avalia a expressão e o respectivo resultado é colocado na lista final.

O que pode ter confundido é que a expressão em si é uma comparação, mas isso não quer dizer que "tem um `if`" ali.

---

Só para completar, também é possível ter uma condição na *list comprehension* (ou seja, um `if`):

```py
lista = [ expressão for i in iterável if condição ]
```

Neste caso é equivalente a:

```py
lista = []
for i in iterável:
    if condição:
        lista.append(expressão)
```

Mas no seu caso não tem o `if`.

Comment: Cara, muito obrigado. Muito bem explicado!!!

Answer (score -2):

Se não estou errado, para cada iteração, ele faz a comparação e se a comparação for verdadeira, ele devolve o valor iterado.

```py
list_liked = [i >= 4 for i in ratings]
```

Faz o mesmo que:

```py
list_liked = []
for i in ratings:
    if i >= 4:
        list_liked.append(i)
```

Comment: Não, esses códigos não são equivalentes. O primeiro gera uma lista de booleanos, enquanto o segundo gera uma lista com os próprios valores de `i`. Veja a diferena: https://ideone.com/43rz9R

Comment: *...Se não estou errado, para cada iteração, ele faz a comparação e se a comparação for verdadeira, ele devolve o valor iterado....* .Sim você está errado! A cada iteração é apensado o resultado da comparação `i >= 4` a lista em construção.